# How to run two if conditions alternatively in commit-msg hook?

Tags: bash, shell, husky

I have a `commit-msg` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This hook enforces commit messages to follow the rules

# ANSI color codes for formatting
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

commit_msg="$1"
error_msg="${RED}error: Commit message must start with a capitalized verb${NC}"
error_length_msg="${RED}error: Commit message must be more than 20 characters${NC}"

# Use regex to check if the message starts with a capitalized verb
if ! echo "$commit_msg" | grep -qE "^[A-Z][a-z]+"; then
  echo "$error_msg" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Check the length of the commit message
if [ ${#commit_msg} -le 20 ]; then
  echo "$error_length_msg"
  exit 1
fi
```

When I do a commit message with lower letter in the begining, it executes the first check well:

```
git commit -m "test capital letter"
error: Commit message must start with a capitalized verb
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

However, when the commit message start with capital but less than 20 letters, it stills show ( execute ) the first message:

```
git commit -m "Test 20 letters"
error: Commit message must start with a capitalized verb
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

My **pre-commit:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"


# Run the commit message check
.husky/commit-msg `$1`

# Check the exit status of the previous command
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  exit 1
fi

# Run linting and lint-staged checks
npx lint-staged

# ANSI color codes for formatting
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

# Check the exit status of the previous command
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "${RED}Linting failed. Aborting commit.${NC}"
  exit 1
fi

# Run Cypress tests without opening the launchpad
npm run cypress-run-component
```

Based on Philip's answer

```
#!/bin/sh

# This hook enforces commit messages to follow the rules

# ANSI color codes for formatting
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

commit_msg=`cat $1` // changed this

error_msg="${RED}error: Commit message must start with a capitalized verb${NC}"
error_length_msg="${RED}error: Commit message must be more than 20 characters${NC}"

# Use regex to check if the message starts with a capitalized verb
if ! echo "$commit_msg" | grep -qE "^[A-Z][a-z]+"; then
  echo "$error_msg" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Check the length of the commit message
if [ ${#commit_msg} -le 20 ]; then
  echo "$error_length_msg"
  exit 1
fi
```

**Output**

---

`git commit -m "Test 20 letters"`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`$1` is not the commit mesage, but the name of the file containing commit message, so you need :

```
commit_msg=`cat $1`
```

Comment: I changed but I got the same issue: `git commit -m "Cat"
error: Commit message must start with a capitalized verb
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)`

Comment: Based on the message : `husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1`, you have errors in `pre-commit` hook.

Comment: I shared my pre-commit hook.